# How to make Apache Tika find text in .java and .xml (etc.) files

Tags: java, apache-tika

OK. I figured out how to use Apache Tika for searching some of the file types it can handle without my supplying more code than exists in `tika-example`:

```
public class MyFirstTika {

  public static boolean contains(File file, String s) throws MalformedURLException, 
     IOException, MimeTypeException, SAXException, TikaException{

    ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();

    MimeTypes mimeRegistry = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig().getMimeRepository();

    Detector mimeDetector = (Detector) mimeRegistry;

    LanguageIdentifier lang = new LanguageIdentifier(new LanguageProfile(FileUtils.readFileToString(file)));

    Parser parser = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig().getParser(MediaType.parse(mimeRegistry.getMimeType(file).getName()));

    Metadata parsedMet = new Metadata();

    parser.parse(file.toURI().toURL().openStream(), handler,parsedMet, new ParseContext());

    return handler.toString().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
  {
    String searchString = "champion";
    String filename = "schedule.pdf"; //test.docx";//"meds.xlsx";//Test2.Doc";
    File file = new File(filename);

    System.out.println(file + " contains " + searchString + ": " 
            + contains(file, searchString));
    }
}
```

The above can tell whether the following file types contain a word or phrase:
.doc
.docx
.xlsx
.pdf
.txt
.html

It doesn't work for `.java` files or `.xml` files.

(a) What do I have to do I want to see if a text file with extension `.java` or `.xml` file contains a word or phrase?

(b) Those are not the only types of files that I routinely create or edit. Is there a way to have Apache Tika detect if a file is a text file without specifying its extension?

*EDIT* Background: I've written a search program for Windows that works better than the search command. Now I'm trying to add searching for specific text within pattern-matched files.

***EDIT***

Here's the output of the program (modified to supply the info below) when I have it search for `void` in `Copy.java`:

```
Examining: [copy.java]
The MIME type (based on filename) is: [text/x-java-source]
The MIME type (based on MAGIC) is: [application/octet-stream
The MIME type (based on the Detector interface) is: [text/plain]
The language of this content is: [et]
Parsed Metadata: 

Parsed Text: 

copy.java contains void: false
```

So why didn't it find `void`? (Answer: because **it didn't find any `Parsed Metadata` or `Parsed Text`, but why didn't it find those**? It should have displayed the entire file.

I copied `copy.java` to `copy.txt`. Program DID find `void`. Same thing happened when I copied `build.xml` to `build.txt`.

Maybe this added info helps answer the question: "How do I handle `.java` and `.xml` and other text files such as `.c`, etc.?"

PLEASE NOTE the output from searching `copy.TXT`:

```
run:
Examining: [copy.TXT]
The MIME type (based on filename) is: [text/plain]
The MIME type (based on MAGIC) is: [application/octet-stream
The MIME type (based on the Detector interface) is: [text/plain]
The language of this content is: [et]
```

**Parsed Metadata:**

```
Content-Encoding=UTF-8 Content-Type=text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

**Parsed Text:**

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        { @Override
          public void run() { 
               insUserIO = new UserIO(); 
          }
        }
    ); 
  }

copy.TXT contains void: true
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

*ENTIRE REVISED PROGRAM*

```
    package org.apache.tika.example;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;

    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    import org.apache.tika.config.TikaConfig;
    import org.apache.tika.detect.Detector;
    import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
    import org.apache.tika.language.LanguageIdentifier;
    import org.apache.tika.language.LanguageProfile;
    import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
    import org.apache.tika.mime.MediaType;
    import org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypeException;
    import org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypes;
    import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
    import org.apache.tika.parser.Parser;
    import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
    import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

    public class MyFirstTika {

      static boolean debugging = true;

      public static boolean contains(File file, String s) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, MimeTypeException, SAXException, TikaException{

        ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();

            MimeTypes mimeRegistry = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig()
                    .getMimeRepository();

            if(debugging) System.out.println("Examining: [" + file + "]");

            if(debugging) System.out.println("The MIME type (based on filename) is: ["
                    + mimeRegistry.getMimeType(file.toString()) + "]");

            if(debugging) System.out.println("The MIME type (based on MAGIC) is: ["
                    + mimeRegistry.getMimeType(file + "]"));

            Detector mimeDetector = (Detector) mimeRegistry;
            if(debugging) System.out
                    .println("The MIME type (based on the Detector interface) is: ["
                            + mimeDetector.detect(file.toURI().toURL()
                                    .openStream(), new Metadata()) + "]");

            LanguageIdentifier lang = new LanguageIdentifier(new LanguageProfile(
                    FileUtils.readFileToString(file)));

            if(debugging) System.out.println("The language of this content is: ["
                    + lang.getLanguage() + "]");

            Parser parser = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig().getParser(
                    MediaType.parse(mimeRegistry.getMimeType(file).getName()));

        Metadata parsedMet = new Metadata();
            parser.parse(file.toURI().toURL().openStream(), handler,
                    parsedMet, new ParseContext());

            if(debugging) System.out.println("Parsed Metadata: ");
            if(debugging) System.out.println(parsedMet);
            if(debugging) System.out.println("Parsed Text: ");
            if(debugging) System.out.println(handler.toString());
        return handler.toString().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase());
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
        File file = new File(filename);

        System.out.println(file + " contains " + searchString + ": " 
                + contains(file, searchString));
        }

        static String searchString = "void";
        static String filename = "copy.TXT";
    }
```

Comment: What version of Apache Tika are you using? And if it isn't the most recent (1.10 as of August 2015), what happens if you upgrade?

Comment: @Gagravarr--I downloaded 1.9 a few days ago. I didn't ask for 1.9 or 1.10, I just took what was shown atop www,apache.tika that day. But it seems that since `.java` and `.xml` files are ASCII text (aren't they?) the text parser should work as well for them as for `.txt`. Is that wrong?

Comment: Apache Tika has a bunch of JUnit unit tests which are able to extract textual content of java and xml files, so you must be doing something wrong. What happens if you follow the examples on the Tika website, and use a simple `AutoDetectParser` rather than your current strange and complicated setup?

Comment: Heh... that IS an example from `tika-example` (named `MyFirstTika.java`) that was downloaded along with the `.jar` file. The comment from the original file is this: `/**
 * Demonstrates how to call the different components within Tika: its
 * {@link Detector} framework (aka MIME identification and repository), its  * {@link Parser} interface, its {@link LanguageIdentifier} and other goodies. */` There are 32 `.java` files to choose from; this one seemed logical. Five of them contain `autoDetectParser`. I'll check them out.

Comment: The examples I'd suggest are the ones that get pulled through to the website at http://tika.apache.org/1.10/examples.html - I think I know who wrote that complicated and confusion example, but I'll keep quiet to spare the guilty... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THANKS EVER SO MUCH TO @Gagravarr for steering me to `AutoDetectParser`!

The little program below found text in ALL KINDS of "text" (human-readable) (and other--e.g., `.doc*`) files, including `private.properties`, `ParsingExample.java` (itself!), `test.doc`, `test.pdf` (produced by Word), `gradlew.bat`, etc., etc.

```
package org.apache.tika.example;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypeException;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ParsingExample {

  public static boolean contains(File file, String s) throws MalformedURLException, 
                     IOException, MimeTypeException, SAXException, TikaException
  {
    InputStream         stream    = new FileInputStream(file);
    AutoDetectParser    parser    = new AutoDetectParser();
    BodyContentHandler  handler   = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
    Metadata            metadata  = new Metadata();
    try{
      parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
      return handler.toString().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase());
    }
    catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException e){
      System.out.println(file + ": " + e + "\n");
      return false;
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      try {
        System.out.println("File " + filename + " contains <" + searchString + "> : " 
          + contains(new File(filename), searchString));
      } catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException ex){
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
      }
  }   

  static String parseExample = ":(";
  static String searchString = "slom";
  static String filename = "C:\\Users\\Dov\\x.pdf"; 
}
    /**
     * Example of how to use Tika to parse a file when you do not know its file type
     * ahead of time.
     *
     * AutoDetectParser attempts to discover the file's type automatically, then call
     * the exact Parser built for that file type.
     *
     * The stream to be parsed by the Parser. In this case, we get a file from the
     * resources folder of this project.
     *
     * Handlers are used to get the exact information you want out of the host of
     * information gathered by Parsers. The body content handler, intuitively, extracts
     * everything that would go between HTML body tags.
     *
     * The Metadata object will be filled by the Parser with Metadata discovered about
     * the file being parsed.
     *
     * Note: This example will extract content from the outer document and all
     * embedded documents.  However, if you choose to use a {@link ParseContext},
     * make sure to set a {@link Parser} or else embedded content will not be
     * parsed.
     *
     * @return The content of a file.
   * I let Netbeans add next 3 lines: 
   * @throws java.io.IOException
   * @throws org.xml.sax.SAXException
   * @throws org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException
     */
```

Comment: Instead of a `FileInputStream`, I'd suggest you do `InputStream stream = TikaInputStream.get(file)` - it'll be slightly quicker and lower memory on some file types